# Does fourier series for $f(x)=\begin{cases}-1\ \text{for}\ x \in (-\pi, 0) \\0 \ \text{for}\ x=0 \\ 1 \ \text{for} \ x\in (0,\pi)\end{cases}$ converge

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, fourier-series, uniform-convergence, pointwise-convergence

> Does the Fourier series for the $2\pi$ periodic function
> $$f(x) = \begin{cases} -1 \ \text{for} \ x \in (-\pi, 0) \\\\
> 0 \ \text{for} \ x = 0 \\\\
> 1 \ \text{for} \ x \in (0,\pi) \end{cases} $$ converge uniformly or pointwise?

$f(x)$ is discontinuous in $x=0$ so the Fourier series cannot converge uniformly, but why not?

The Fourier series will converge towards $f(x)$ in all continuous points and in the discontinuity ($x=0$) it will converge towards $\frac{f(0^+) + f(0^-)}{2} = \frac{1-1}{2} = 0 $. So indeed, the Fourier series does converge towards $f(x)$ in all points, but why does it not do it uniformly? How can it be shown with the definition of uniform convergence for series?

> The series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n(x), x \in I$ is said to converge uniformly towards $f(x)$ on $I$ if there for any $\varepsilon > 0$ exists an $N_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that
> $$ \bigg| f(x) - \sum_{n=1}^N f_n(x) \bigg| < \varepsilon $$
> for all $x\in I$ and all $N\geq N_0$.

When is this definition violated in the case above?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to prove it with the definition?

Comment: @SineoftheTime If I understand the definition correctly, if it is violated, it means that there is an $x \in I$ for which there does not exist an $N_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that the error $| f(x) - \sum_{n=1}^{N_0} f_n(x) |$ is less than $\varepsilon$. I am interested in when this happens for this case.

Answer (score 1):

This does not answer your question exactly, but it may clarify some things for you.  The first step is to calculate the Fourier coefficients .
$$\boxed{f(x)=\frac{1}{2}a_0+\sum_{n\ge 1} a_n\cos(nx)+b_n\sin(nx)}$$
convegence Uniformily if $\sum a_n $ and $\sum b_n $ absolument convege

we have function f odd then
$$a_0=a_n=0$$
$$b_n=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}f(x)\sin(nx) dx = \frac{2}{\pi}\sin(nx) dx = \frac{2}{\pi}\left({\frac{1-(-1)^n}{n}}\right)$$

therfore :
$$\boxed{f(x)=\sum_{n\ge 1} 2\left({\frac{1-(-1)^n}{n\pi}}\right)\sin(nx)}$$

we have : $ \sum |b_n| $ Not absolument converge

finnaly : f(x) does not convergence uniform

Answer (score 1):

No, it does not converge uniformly.
Indeed, the partial sums of the Fourier series are continuous functions.  By a standard real-anaysis theorem: if a sequence of continuous functions converges uniformly, then the limit is continuous.  So we only have to observe that this function $f$ is not continuous at $0$.  So: the Fourier series does not converge uniformly on any neighborhood of $0$.

Comment: Does the Fourier series converge uniformly at $x=0$ at least?

Comment: What does it mean to converge uniformly *at a point*?  [I know only the definition for uniform convergence *on a set*.]  Perhaps you want uniform convergence on some neighborhood of $0$?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I want. Can you show that in a neighborhood of $0$ the requirement for uniform convergence is violated?

Comment: That explanation is in this answer.

Comment: I mean how does it violate the definition given in my question above?